# Magento checkout stuck at billing address

Tags: php, html, css, magento, checkout

I am having a strange issue. I have not been doing changes or anything to my shop, but suddenly my customers are stuck at the billing step of my checkout. It just returns that **"all '*' needs to be filled out."**

Any idea how I troubleshoot/fix this? My URL is [canopysound](http://canopysound.dk) (it is in Danish, but I guess you can navigate to the checkout anyway).

Another thing is that in my backend configuration I am not able to save changes I do. I tried turning off guest checkout and one page checkout. When I press "save" they stay the same (both on). I don't know if this is related or not :/

EDIT:
I have done some more searching around regarding the last mentioned issue. It could have something to do with my .htaccess configuration. I may have ruined something there. My .htaccesss looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
  RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "I have not been doing changes or anything to my shop" If there is a change in the behavior, there must have been a change to the code or settings.

Comment: I just can't relate this issue to anything... :/

Comment: Check the Magento error logs ... here is a short article about this topic: http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-error-logs/

Comment: It now seems I can save no changes in the backend. It says configuration updated, but nothing changes

Comment: @Viktor "It says" Who said what? Where was it written? How does the conmplete error message look like? More details please!

Comment: _If there is a change in the behavior, there must have been a change to the code or settings._ Three external items that can quickly bring things to a halt with no changes. 1) Running out of disk space. 2) Having a limit set on the allowed database storage and exceeding that limit. 3) Hosting provider installs updates/patches that gives Magento a heart attack.